# GCP OCR Service - Convert Scanned PDF or Image to a Searchable PDF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr

Is possible to convert Scanned PDF to **new Searchable PDF file** using OCR 
Service from Google Cloud Platform ?

Answer (score 1):

This feature where the source file is an image PDF and the output is a searchable PDF is not directly offered with Google [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). You can submit a feature request about it at [Issue Tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com). However, Vision API OCR can return the actual positions of the words detected in the scanned document (image format) like this [example](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr). In order to make your text on an image searchable, you may try to make use of each words’ `boundingPoly`. The easiest solution could be creating a table with words and their `boundingPoly` location, and map that to the document image.

Note that if the original scanned document is in PDF format, you would have to convert it first to a supported image file before using the vision API. You may also have to use third party solutions to convert the produced file back to PDF.

Furthermore, if you want to extract text from an image and convert it to PDF  without extracting diagrams, pictures, tables .. etc.,  you may check this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr).

Comment: Hi, how to generate a pdf file from text is easy, but transform the scanned pdf that contains images, tables, etc  in a new searchable pdf is not trivial.

Comment: @Gus I modified my answer to reflect on your clarification of the question. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Possible to convert Scanned PDF to new Searchable PDF file using OCR Service, you can look for LeadTools and Amazon Textract services